# React Compose Components not Rendering Properly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

My project is separated into parts, and some parts got so big I even separated them using composition on sub components.

The problem is, the compose components are rendering, but aren't interactive, for instance, here's a menu component that contains a header with a button:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Menu() {

    // This is responsible of creating a custom button with bunch of things in it, that button should rotate 180deg when hovered.
    function IconButton() {
        return (
            <div class='rotating_button'>
                // Bunch of code...
                <button></button>
                // Bunch of other code...
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div class='menu'>
            <IconButton />
            // The rest of the Menu Code.
        </div>
    );
}
```

Everything till now seems fine, but when I wanna make a compose component interactive through something like CSS or other JavaScript file, it doesn't animate, or it doesn't render as expected.

Here's my CSS my code that in this case should make the custom button rotatable when hovered, and it's so simple it doesn't work:

```
.rotating_button {
   /* All of this works. */
    background_color: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);

   /* But this does not. */
   transition: 0.5s;
}
.rotating_button:is(:hover, :focus) {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

To summarize, it rotates, but with no transition applied on it.

But when it's not a compose component, and it's directly put in the **return** section of the Menu Component, it works just write.

Suchlike this code:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Menu() {
    return (
        <div class='menu'>
            <div class='rotating_button'>
                // Bunch of code...
                <button></button>
                // Bunch of other code...
            </div>
            // The rest of the Menu Code.
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You need to use `className` not `class` attribute, `class` is reserved keyword in JavaScript.

Comment: Also consider declaring `IconButton` outside from `Menu`. Due to how React render DOM, it will recreate the DOM on every Menu render.

Comment: @GabrielPichot thanks but the *class* keyword worked just fine in all of my project, and I didn't really see any difference between it and the *className* keyword. I was actually using them both unconsciously, is there a real difference?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html
Also use the complete version: `transition: transform 0.5s ease;` for instance